# want to execute startHandler() and useHandler() individually (i.e when one function is executing other should stop) but the are working simultaneously

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here is the following code:

```
 state = {
    percentage: 0,
    visible: true,
    use: false
  };

 startHandler =() =>{                                       //use to start the timmer (i.e from 0 to 100)
     let status= this.state.percentage;

    const g=(status, callback)=>{
      if(status<=100 && !this.state.use)
      {
        //console.log(this.state.use)
        callback(status)
        status++;
        g(status, callback)
      }
      else
        return
    }  
    const k=(status)=>{
        setTimeout((status)=>{
            this.setState({percentage: status})
        }, status*1000, status);
    }
    g(status,k)
  }

  useHandler=()=>{                                               //used for contdown   
    let status= this.state.percentage;
    let temp=0;
    this.setState({use: true})
    //console.log(this.state.use)
    const g=(status, callback, temp)=>{
      if(status>=0)
      {
        callback(status,temp)
        status--;
        temp++;
        g(status, callback, temp)
      }
      else
        return
    }
```

I am actually working on a react project where i want a countup and countdown system. Both the above functions have been set withe the button start and use using onClick. I was expecting something like if i press the start button then after 20 second the percentage will become 20 and then after clicking the use button the starHandler() function will stop executing and the percentage will decrease till 0. But i think that both the functions are executing simultaneously resulting in unexpected percentage result.
Please help me out and also provide the reason for such unexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really get my head around what the code is trying to do. but from what I understood here is how it usually works

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
    this.timeOut = null;
  }

  startHandler() {
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.count += 20;
      ...
    }, 20000);
  }

  useHandler() {
    if (this.timeOut) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeOut); 
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I used the reference of 20 just as an example. The function startHandler() will count up from 0 to 100 with an interval of 1 second between each countup and useHandler() function will countdown from the number when it is called till 0 with 1second interval between each countdown.

Answer (score 0):

don't use abbreviation like `const g = ...` Others devs would have to read the whole thing to understand what g means ;)

You should have only one function to interact with the counter, not 2. You can define state to modify the behiavor of how the counter is updating.

To update the counter, I would use a lifecycle event like this :

```js
constructor(){
    this.interval = undefined
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.YOUR_CALLBACK)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.YOUR_CALLBACK)
}
```